# Modify Orchard Archive Filter

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6, orchardcms-1.7, orchard-modules

I am new to Orchard CMS may be this can be easily achievable I don't know how to do it exactly as i have searched a lot on Google. I have a blog where I need to display the archive in drop down Eg :

[image: Archive Format]

I checked the blog module and I don't know how can I filter it so that I can get this. Do I have to create a new module to achieve this or a tweak in the Blog module will work. I Read the sky-walker tutorial to understand how to create a module but i don't know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the `Parts.Blogs.BlogArchives.cshtml`, very easy. That is what Orchard is all about.
 you can read more about it in the documentation.
Check this [Accessing Shapes](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Accessing-and-rendering-shapes) , for starters.

Comment: I know this that this can be done through shapes but I am not getting the blog post title in this shape so that i can loop it.

Comment: In that case, you probably should create your own Extension. You see '@Html.UnorderedList', ArchiveData has a PageId. You could grab it from there. Also, you can look how RecentBlogPosts is done, that might help show how to get a widget.